# Python ftplib OSError: [WinError 10013] on STOR operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftplib

I have a python3 program that is uploading a large number of files using `ftplib`.

It works fine but will occasionally throw the following exception during a random point in the upload:

```
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bulk_box_ftp.py", line 90, in push_folder_contents
    placeFiles(ftp_conn, folder)
  File "bulk_box_ftp.py", line 68, in placeFiles
    placeFiles(ftp, localpath)
  File "bulk_box_ftp.py", line 52, in placeFiles
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + name, upfile)
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 503, in storbinary
    self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 278, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 251, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 236, in getresp
    resp = self.getmultiline()
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 222, in getmultiline
    line = self.getline()
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 204, in getline
    line = self.file.readline(self.maxline + 1)
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 871, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Following this `OSError` all other files in the queue will then throw a `ConnectionResetError`

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

What could be causing this exception to be raised? Is there any way that I can safely catch it and recover to continue the FTP operations?

Comment: You need to connect again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I found that the FTP connection has to preform a full reset. I wrapped all of my FTP upload code within a `try:` block and catch when an `OSError` is raised:

```
except OSError as e:
  print("FTP Connection Error Occurred")
  attempt_conn_reset(current_pwd)
```

And this function will terminate and re-establish the FTP connection:

```
def attempt_conn_reset(pwd="/"):
  # resets the FTP connection in case of a socket disconnect
  print("Attempting FTP reconnect")
  try:
      ftp_conn.quit()
  except ConnectionResetError:
    print("Connection was already closed")
  # allow OS to release port
  time.sleep(2)
  ftp_conn.connect(FTP_URL)
  ftp_conn.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASSWORD)
  ftp_conn.prot_p()
  ftp_conn.cwd(pwd)
  print("FTP connection has been reset")
```